# Scrollable frame class in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have implemented my own scrollable frame class in tkinter:

```
class scrolledFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.pack(fill = "both", expand = True, side = "left")
        self.scroll = tk.Scrollbar(self, command = self.canvas.yview)
        self.scroll.pack(side = "right", fill = "y")
        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand = self.scroll.set)
        self.content = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.content.bind("<Configure>", self.resizeCanvas)
        self.contentWindow = self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window = self.content, anchor = "nw")
        self.content.bind("<Enter>", self.enableScrollCanvas)
        self.content.bind("<Leave>", self.disableScrollCanvas)
    def scrollCanvas(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")
    def enableScrollCanvas(self, event):
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.scrollCanvas)
    def disableScrollCanvas(self, event):
        self.canvas.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>")
    def resizeCanvas(self, event):
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.contentWindow, width = self.canvas.winfo_width())

root = tk.Tk()
exampleFrame = scrolledFrame(root)
exampleFrame.pack()
exampleLabel = tk.Label(exampleFrame.content, text = "I'm in the scrolled frame!")
exampleLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

This works fine, but the problem is to add widgets to the scrolled frame, the parent has to be `exampleFrame.content`. I have looked at several other examples which all have the same limitation. Is it possible to configure the class so `exampleFrame` can be the parent of the widgets instead of `exampleFrame.content`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The key is to implement a getattr method. [Here's how I did it](https://gist.github.com/novel-yet-trivial/3eddfce704db3082e38c84664fc1fdf8).

Comment: @Novel Is it line 43 that makes this work?

Comment: kinda, that is used in the `__getattr__` which does the delegation.

Comment: @Novel I've tried adding the `__getattr__` method to my class and the `self.outer_attr =` line but it doesn't seem to work. Is it because my class subclasses `tk.Frame` or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Your diagnosis is exactly right. You can't use a subclass with the `__getattr__` trick because that only works for undefined attributes. You could use `__getattribute__` instead, but that would be a lot more complex to implement. Or you reimplement all of the relevant attributes manually. Or just don't use a subclass.

Comment: @Novel I think I just won't use a subclass then. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind a little trickery, you can simulate what you want. It's a bit of a hack though.

The trick is that when you call `tk.Frame.__init__`, you need to be giving it the canvas as the parent, making `self` the content frame.  Of course, to do that you have to create the canvas first, and to create the canvas you have to create the outer frame.

It looks something like this:

```
class scrolledFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.outer = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.outer)
        self.scroll = tk.Scrollbar(self.outer, command = self.canvas.yview)
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.contentWindow = self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window = self, anchor = "nw")
```

However, when you do the above and you try to call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on the instance of `scrolledFrame` it's going to do the wrong thing since the instance points to the inner frame rather than the outer frame.

Here's the trickery: the solution to that is to redirect calls to `pack`, `place`, and `grid` to the outer frame.

```
class scrolledFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ...
        self.pack = self.outer.pack
        self.place = self.outer.place
        self.grid = self.outer.grid
```

With that, you can use `scrolledFrame` like you want, as long as you use `pack`, `place`, or `grid` when adding it to the layout.

```
exampleFrame = scrolledFrame(root)
exampleFrame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
for i in range(100):
    exampleLabel = tk.Label(exampleFrame, text = f"I'm in the scrolled frame! ({i})")
    exampleLabel.pack()
```

---

Here's a complete working example, though I've removed the mousewheel code for brevity.

```
import tkinter as tk

class scrolledFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.outer = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.outer)
        self.scroll = tk.Scrollbar(self.outer, command = self.canvas.yview)
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.contentWindow = self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window = self, anchor = "nw")

        self.canvas.pack(fill = "both", expand = True, side = "left")
        self.scroll.pack(side = "right", fill = "y")
        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand = self.scroll.set)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.resizeCanvas)

        self.pack = self.outer.pack
        self.place = self.outer.place
        self.grid = self.outer.grid

    def resizeCanvas(self, event):
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.contentWindow, width = self.canvas.winfo_width())

root = tk.Tk()
exampleFrame = scrolledFrame(root)
exampleFrame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
for i in range(100):
    exampleLabel = tk.Label(exampleFrame, text = f"I'm in the scrolled frame! ({i})")
    exampleLabel.pack(fill="x")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Novel for their help answering this question.
The desired behaviour can be achieved by adding a `__getattr__` method to the class. This won't work if the class inherits from `tk.Frame` so that's been removed. Here's the code:

```
class scrolledFrame():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.wrapper = tk.Frame(parent)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.wrapper)
        self.canvas.pack(fill = "both", expand = True, side = "left")
        self.scroll = tk.Scrollbar(self.wrapper, command = self.canvas.yview)
        self.scroll.pack(side = "right", fill = "y")
        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand = self.scroll.set)
        self.content = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.content.bind("<Configure>", self.resizeCanvas)
        self.contentWindow = self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window = self.content, anchor = "nw")
        self.content.bind("<Enter>", self.enableScrollCanvas)
        self.content.bind("<Leave>", self.disableScrollCanvas)
        self.attrib = set(dir(tk.Widget))
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item in self.attrib:
            return getattr(self.wrapper, item)
        else:
            return getattr(self.content, item)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.wrapper)
    def scrollCanvas(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")
    def enableScrollCanvas(self, event):
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.scrollCanvas)
    def disableScrollCanvas(self, event):
        self.canvas.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>")
    def resizeCanvas(self, event):
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.contentWindow, width = self.canvas.winfo_width())
root = tk.Tk()
exampleFrame = scrolledFrame(root)
exampleFrame.pack()
exampleLabel = tk.Label(exampleFrame, text = "I'm in the scrolled frame!")
exampleLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```